# Efficiently using data in multiple classes

Tags: php, oop

I'm pulling in JSON from an external URL.  I then want to use that data in two different classes.  Here's how I think it should be setup.

```
// gets data
class get_data {

}

// creates a widget that uses the data
class widget_class {

}

// some other widget that uses the data
class page_class {

}
```

How do I get the data from get_data into both widget_class and page_class?  I could just insert something like `$data = new get_data();` in each class, but that's not the most efficient way of doing things since it would pull the external data twice, right?

My knowledge of OOP is limited, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the two classes in tandem using a *factory*.

The factory is a third class which has a static method returning both a page_class and a widget_class. It makes one get_data call and then appropriately splits up the return as it constructs the two classes.

Comment: Righhht, I think I gotchya.  I'll do some Googling on the best way to do this to fit my needs :)  Thanks for getting me started.

Comment: would I want to set get_data as an interface, and then implement that interface on class creation, or is that just replicating my original problem?

Comment: @ruescher: if you're not using the get_data except to build the other two classes, just make it a function on the factory rather than its own object type.

Comment: I have this http://pastebin.com/xxaEwz9j, and I think this is what you're suggesting.  If this is correct, then how do I 1) pass the data to each class, and then 2) use it in each class?

Comment: @ruescher: I'm sorry, there's not enough there that I can help with this. You're going to have to write a bit more code. Each class should have member variables, member functions, and a constructor. The data will be passed in to the constructor.

Comment: right.  I'll play with this for a bit, I have two different things.  I'll post up something when I'm done messing around. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I think this may all be fubared since I'm working with WordPress, and to create a widget it uses a pre-existing function `register_widget()` which accepts my class as an arguement.  I have no idea how to pass data to my class if it's instantiated with that function.

Comment: for whatever it's worth, there appears to be some kind of __construct function when extending WP_Widget in WordPress.  I stored my data into a variable, and set it to global within that function when I wrote the class.  I also then just passed that variable (containing data) to my other class (and it's __construct function).  I don't know how clean it is, but it works, and I'm fairly certain it's only pulling data once since I'm using the same variable.